# String-Object mismatch for hashlist in java

Tags: java, hashtable, type-mismatch

I have a problem with my hashtable. The for loop that I used in a method works correctly but same loop that is in the main gives an (cannot convert String to Object) error. If there is a mismatch, why don't my method give an error?

i will write down the declaration of the hashlist object. The loop that is in main and the method

declaration:

```
private static Hashtable hashlist2;
hashlist2 = new Hashtable<String,Course>();
```

method:

```
private static void printmap(Hashtable<String,Course> hashlist, LinkedList<Course> list){       
    for(String courses : hashlist.keySet()){
        hashlist.get(courses).print();
    }
```

the for loop that i use in main:

```
            for(String courses : hashlist2.keySet()){//mismatch occurs here
                if(courses.equals(coursecode)){
                ((Course) hashlist2.get(courses)).print();
                    check=true;//means "yeah we find a course"
                    break;//and break there no more loop needed
                }                   
            }
```

Comment: You are using raw types. Try with `private static Hashtable<String, Course> hashlist2;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because argument passed to `printmap` is of type `Hashtable<String,Course> hashlist`, Whereas in `main` you declared `private static Hashtable hashlist2; hashlist2 = new Hashtable();` which is non-generic version(That's why when you iterate in for-loop you get object instead of String), you can fix it by `private static Hashtable<String,Course> hashlist2;`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
private static Hashtable hashlist2;
hashlist2 = new Hashtable<String,Course>()
```

to

```
private static Hashtable<String,Course> hashlist2;
hashlist2 = new Hashtable<String,Course>()
```

When you use the raw type `Hashtable`, the compiler doesn't know that the keys are of type `String`, so `for(String courses : hashlist2.keySet())` cannot pass compilation. For raw `Hashtable` the key is assumed to be of type `Object`.